# Creating a list programatilly using countif

Tags: google-sheets-formula, countif

I have one Sheet with Groceries items, when I bought them and for how much.

I'm trying to create a new list, programatilly, that search in the first list for every purchases of a item and the total money spend on that item, in a given period.

Raw data:

```
A       B       C
Item    Date    Price
Cheese  20/08   16,60
Bacon   20/08   8,35
Chicken 20/08   10,90
Butter  20/08   7,99
Tea     20/08   3,75
Bread   20/08   4,89
Bread   21/08   4,50
Milk    21/08   8
```

Second list:

```
E           F
Item        Total
(formula 1) (formula 2)
```

formula1 : `=INDEX(A2:A;MATCH(0;COUNTIFS($E$1:E1;A2:A);0))`

formula2 : `=sumifs(C:C;A:A;E2;B:B;CONCAT(">=";INDIRECT("I1"));B:B;CONCAT("<=";INDIRECT("I2")))`

where,

I1: Start date

I2: End date

this works fine if I set the date to be from start of the data (20/08) until the end (21/08)

```
E       F
Item    Total
Cheese  $16,60
Bacon   $8,35
Chicken $10,90
Butter  $7,99
Tea     $3,75
Bread   $9,39
Milk    $8,00
```

but if I set the start and end date to 21/08. It shows a bunch of zeros in the F column. Which is what Im trying to fix.

```
E       F
Item    Total
Cheese  $0,00
Bacon   $0,00
Chicken $0,00
Butter  $0,00
Tea     $0,00
Bread   $4,50
Milk    $8,00
```

What I want is it to show like this:

```
E       F
Item    Total
Bread   $4,50
Milk    $8,00
```

I tried modifying formula 1 to

`=INDEX(A2:A;MATCH(0;COUNTIFS($E$1:E1;A2:A;B:B;CONCAT(">=";INDIRECT("I1"));B:B;CONCAT("<=";INDIRECT("I2")));0))`

but I'm getting a #VALUE error ("Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a unique item list with a date limit use the formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9;MATCH(1;(COUNTIF($E$1:E1;$A$2:$A$9)=0)*($B$2:$B$9>=$I$1)*($B$2:$B$9<=$I$2);0))
```

To get the amount use the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2=$A$2:$A$9)*($B$2:$B$9>=$I$1)*($B$2:$B$9<=$I$2)*$C$2:$C$9)
```

[image]

If you want to get rid of `#N/A` errors, use `IFERROR` with the first formula and `IF(E2<>""; ..., "")` with the second

Comment: That works beautifully, didnt know about the multiplication of the conditionals. Is there are name for that so I can read more about it?

Comment: I don't know how to call it, but it is based on ```bool``` conversion to an ```int``` value by doing a mathematical operation with ```bool```, ```TRUE``` is converted to ```1``` and ```FALSE``` to ```0```. Respectively - if the values are summed, the ```OR``` logic is used, if multiplied, then the ```AND``` logic. Ex: ```TRUE OR FALSE = TRUE``` => ```1 + 0 = 1``` or ```TRUE AND FALSE = FALSE``` => ```1 * 0 = 0```

Comment: Ah, that really clever and makes a lot of sense, it's kinda like masking. Thank you!